# How is the paramter onScreenChange : (String) -> Unit passed to the function body : @Composable ((String) -> Unit) -> Unit?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from the main branch of the official sample [project](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/tree/main/NavigationCodelab).

There are three subclass `Overview`, `Accounts` and `Bills` of the enum class `RallyScreen` in the project.

There is a function `fun content(onScreenChange: (String) -> Unit) { body(onScreenChange) }` which accept the paramater `onScreenChange : (String) -> Unit` in the class `RallyScreen`.

Although the statement is `enum class RallyScreen(val body: @Composable ((String) -> Unit) -> Unit) {..}`,  the `body = { OverviewBody() }` in the class `Overview`, the `body = { AccountsBody(UserData.accounts) }`  in the class  `Accounts` and the `body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) }` in the class `Bills` don't require to pass the paramter `(String) -> Unit)`, why can Kotlin run well and navigate by Tab well when the App launch `fun content(onScreenChange: (String) -> Unit) { body(onScreenChange)}` ?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun RallyApp() {
    RallyTheme {
        val allScreens = RallyScreen.values().toList()
        var currentScreen by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(RallyScreen.Overview) }
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                RallyTabRow(
                    allScreens = allScreens,
                    onTabSelected = { screen -> currentScreen = screen },
                    currentScreen = currentScreen
                )
            }
        ) { innerPadding ->
            Box(Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                currentScreen.content(
                    onScreenChange = { screen ->
                        currentScreen = RallyScreen.valueOf(screen)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


enum class RallyScreen(
    val icon: ImageVector,
    val body: @Composable ((String) -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    Overview(
        icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
        body = { OverviewBody() }  
    ),
    Accounts(
        icon = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,
        body = { AccountsBody(UserData.accounts) } 
    ),
    Bills(
        icon = Icons.Filled.MoneyOff,
        body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) } 
    );

    @Composable
    fun content(onScreenChange: (String) -> Unit) {
        body(onScreenChange)
    } 
}


@Composable
fun OverviewBody(
    onClickSeeAllAccounts: () -> Unit = {},
    onClickSeeAllBills: () -> Unit = {},
    onAccountClick: (String) -> Unit = {},
) {
   ...
}

@Composable
fun AccountsBody(
    accounts: List<Account>,
    onAccountClick: (String) -> Unit = {},
) {
    ...
}

@Composable
fun BillsBody(bills: List<Bill>) {
    ...
}
```

**Added Content:**

To Gabriel Pizarro: Thanks!

By the statement of `clas Overview`, the `body` needn't any parameter, it use default values, how is the `onScreenChange` parameter passed ?

```
Overview(
   icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
   body = { OverviewBody() }  //It needn't any parameter
)


@Composable
fun content(onScreenChange: (String) -> Unit) {
   body(onScreenChange)
}
```

And more, the app can work well when I add two default parameters for fun `OverviewBody(...)` .

```
@Composable
fun OverviewBody(
    onClickSeeAllAccounts: () -> Unit = {},
    onClickSeeAllBills: () -> Unit = {},
    a1: (String) -> Unit = {},              // I add
    onAccountClick: (String) -> Unit = {},
    a2: (String) -> Unit = {},              //I add
) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Maybe `body = { OverviewBody() }` should be `body = { OverviewBody(onAccountClick = it) }` in `Overview` class, **right**?

Actually, NO!!!

The lambda that `body` receives is different from `OverviewBody.onAccountClick`. In `body`'s [lambda](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/RallyScreen.kt#L35), the `String` refers to a name of `RallyScreen` as you can see from its usage [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/RallyActivity.kt#L64). And in `onAccountClick` [lambda](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/ui/overview/OverviewScreen.kt#L234), the `String` represents an accountName.

> By the statement of class `Overview`, the `body` needn't any parameter, it use default values, how is the `onScreenChange` parameter passed ?

`onScreenChange` is not <s>passed</s> called anywhere and that's why navigation doesn't work.

You can make the `SEE ALL` buttons in Overview screen work using:

```kotlin
Overview(
    icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
    body = { 
        OverviewBody(
            onClickSeeAllAccounts = { it(Accounts.name) },
            onClickSeeAllBills = { it(Bills.name) },
        ) 
    }
)
```

The `onAccountClick` lambda in `OverviewBody` is tricky to handle. We need to show the [SingleAccountBody](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/ui/accounts/AccountsScreen.kt#L63) composable when [AccountRow](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/ui/overview/OverviewScreen.kt#L234) is clicked. Right now there is no `RallyScreen` corresponding to that composable. So you will have to create a new enum value in `RallyScreen` something like this:

```kotlin
Overview(
    icon = Icons.Filled.PieChart,
    body = {
        OverviewBody(
            onClickSeeAllAccounts = { it(Accounts.name) },
            onClickSeeAllBills = { it(Bills.name) },
            onAccountClick = { accountName ->                   >>>>>>
                it(SingleAccount.name)                                |   
            }                                                         |
        )                                                             | 
    }                                                                 |
),                                                                    |
Accounts(                                                             |
    icon = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,                                  | 
    body = {                                                          | 
        AccountsBody(UserData.accounts)                               |
    }                                                                 |
),                                                                    |
Bills(                                                                |
    icon = Icons.Filled.MoneyOff,                                     |
    body = { BillsBody(UserData.bills) }                              |
),                                                                    | 
SingleAccount(                                                        |
    icon = Icons.Filled.AttachMoney,                                  | 
    body = {                                                          |
        SingleAccountBody(UserData.getAccount(???accountName???)) <<<--
    }
);
```

Here we need to send that `accountName` received from `Overview` screen to `SingleAccount` screen to make the navigation work. But there is no simple way to do that with the current code structure and I don't want to complicate this answer much. In the final code of this codelab, this `accountName` has been passed using NavArguments.

Comment: Thanks! But `"onScreenChange is not passed called anywhere and that's why navigation doesn't work." ` is wrong, the navigation can work well with the main branch of the project when I click a tab icon.

Comment: I meant that Navigation doesn't work when you click on `AccountRow` or `SEE ALL` buttons. Screen changes on tab change because of [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/RallyActivity.kt#L56) line. `onScreenChange` lambda is what is passed to screen [body](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/rally/RallyScreen.kt#L52) to allow navigation in response to events coming from inside screens and that is not called.

Comment: @HelloCW Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that each of the `on` variables is a callback. `onScreenChange` implicitly passes the variable `it` as String, but it is not necessary to use the variable within your callback.

1. `it` is implicitly passed, but in the GitHub link you gave, the programmer decided to rename `it` to `onScreenChange`. That callback then was passed to `OverviewBody`, which overrides the default `{}`, as you said. What I don't understand about your question is where `onAccountClick` is coming from. That is not a parameter of `OverviewBody`, according to the GitHub code.
2. `content` has a parameter for another callback, which you noticed. The `body` variable for each class in the enum is then invoked, and the callback parameter is passed to the invocation. In the future, that callback will only be used by `OverviewBody`. Remember that `body(callback)` is the same as `body.invoke(callback)`.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if anything needs some more explanation.

For further reference:

- [Kotlin Lambda Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html)

Additional Content Edit:

1. I see the parameters in your code, not the one on GitHub. My apologies for missing that.
2. `body` is a variable function. This means that the variable function can be invoked, either by writing `body(...)` or `body.invoke(...)`. The String parameter `it`, which is passed implicitly, is ignored and the default values are used, unless specified like you suggested (`onAccountClick=it`).

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW I expanded upon your question by editing my answer. Basically, `body` isn't using `onScreenChange` because `{ OverviewBody() }` doesn't use `it`. If you changed `body` to `{ OverviewBody(onAccountClick=it) }`, then `onScreenChange` would be passed as parameter `it`.